# Is a flan a pastry?

Tags: pastry

Is a flan classified as pastry or does it just contain pastry? I've searched online without fruition.

Answer (score 5):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flan):

> A flan, in English and other cuisines, is a dish with an open, rimmed **pastry or sponge base** containing a sweet or savoury filling. Examples are the quiche lorraine, custard tart, leche flan, and the South African melktert.

The [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pastry) definition of pastry is

> a dough that is used to make pies and other baked goods and typically has a high fat content

So you can say that the flan is a pastry, since it has a pastry base.

Now if you're thinking flan as the spanish version ([Crème caramel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%A8me_caramel)) then it's not a pastry, it's a custard.

Answer (score 2):

A Latino flan is just a custard.  A French flan is a slightly thicker custard in a pie crust.  So neither ever contains pastry :-).  Custard doesn't qualify as pastry, which always involves some sort of dough.

Comment: a pie crust is not pastry?